# Не убиваются процессы с обходом процессов из List<string> в Windows 10

Tags: c#

Запускаю через админ права

( включая `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` )

Использую список процессов в `List<string>` - Процессы которые не нужно убивать.

```
    var name = new List<string>
    { 
      "svchost", "csrss", "System", "wininit","ApplicationFrameHost",
      "irstrtsv","scrncap","lsass","devenv","System","audiodg","fontdrvhost",
      "wininit","taskmgr","dwm","spoolsv","smss","alg","igfxTray","IpOverUsbSvc",
      "SearchIndexer","lsm","taskhost","svchost","explorer","scrncap","opera",
      "winlogon","services","conhost","ctfmon","ati2evxx","BTTray","nvcontainer",
      "dwm","issch","jusched","rthdcpl","rundll32","wmiprvse","wudfhost","SwiService",
      "AvrcpService","devenv","msvsmon","LMS","jhi_service","nvvsvc","nvcontainer",
      "igfxHK","igfxEM","igfxCUIService","IAStorDataMgrSvc","PerfWatson2","PresentationFontCache",
      "SecurityHealthService","ShellExperienceHost","sihost","SynTPEnh","SynTPEnhService","SynTPHelper",
      "SystemSettings","taskhostw","ViakaraokeSrv","WinStore.App","WUDFHost",
   };
   try
   {
      foreach (var anti in Process.GetProcesses())
      {
        if (name.IndexOf(item: anti.ProcessName.ToLower()) < 0 && anti.ProcessName != Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
        {
            // Обходим все процессы из List<string> и убиваем все остальные.
            anti.Kill();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { File.WriteAllText("ErrorEx.txt", contents: ex.Message); }
```

После запуска убивается максимум один процесс из списка.

Запуск производится на Windows 10.

P.S: ErrorEx.txt - **Отказано в доступе!**

Что ему не хватает :)?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, Разобрался))

Comment: А вы перенесите try/catch внутрь цикла

Comment: @VladD, Так и сделал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ходе следственного эксперимента  выяснил что работая с процессами не к каждому можно получить доступ. В итоге перенёс `try\catch` внутрь цикла `foreach` и оставил его пустым ( чтобы ловил все исключения ) - хоть это и не правильно. Я думаю можно это подправить ( каждый сам под себя найдёт что сделать )

**Решение:**

```
foreach (var anti in Process.GetProcesses())
{
  try
  {
    if (name.IndexOf(item: anti.ProcessName.ToLower()) < 0 && anti.ProcessName != Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
    {
      anti.Kill();
    }
  }
  catch { /*(Exception ex) { File.WriteAllText(path: "ErrorEx.txt", contents: ex.Message); }*/ }
}
```